# Magento, save orders in other Database

Tags: magento

i'd like to save orders in an other database after sending the customer E-Mail (before the observer.php). Where is the right file to get all orders? Maybe /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php?!

Thank you for your help & sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

you need to write an observer for this you have to create an extension.
define the following in the extension's config.xml

```html
<events>
        <sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <store_sales_order_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>companyname_package_model_observer</class>
                    <method>save_new_order</method>
                </store_sales_order_observer>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>
</events>
```

In the observer's model class file please write down the method

```html
<?php
class companyname_Package_Model_Observer 
 public function save_new_order(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
  // all code for storeing goes here
 }
}
?>
```

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: I have extended the xml file with your example code. 
I added your example code between <config>...</config>. Is that correct? Should i create a new Observer.php (path)?

Comment: <!-- language: lang-php -->

include_once("db_config.php");
class saveorder_package_model_observer 
public function save_new_order(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
$orderId = Mage :: getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getCheckout()->getLastOrderId();
$order = Mage :: getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId); 

$dbInsert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO xxx (dg,dt,ew) VALUES(?,?,?)");
$dbInsert->execute(array($orderId,date(Y-m-d),0));
}
}